# Cannot convert this string into an image

Tags: html, jquery, string, image, hex

I need view this string like an image, and i don't understand the format of this. I think that it's in hexadecimal format, but, if i use a online converter, this not working. I tried the convertion in base 64 and putted it html, but same thing its not working. Can someone help me?

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = document.getElementById('source').innerHTML;
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

```html
<span id="source" style="display:none">
    data:image/png;hex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
</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gfptjxvs/

Comment: Your code is correct. The issue is because the hex does not create a valid image.

Comment: ok, so, im sure that this code works, because if i use it inside the software of my company i can view this image. Is this string with another type?

Comment: HTML `img` elements can only show `data;` strings in base64 format. However, even converting this hex string to base64 does not work. The string itself is not a valid image file.

Comment: oh, thx for this information, have you idea which is the format of this string?

Comment: Where are you getting the hex string from?

Comment: from a database of a software in my company. I have about 1200 strings

Comment: I know that this software was made around 2005, i know that there are 3 formats in the software: JPEG, OLE, BMP